# Date value in SharePoint is one day off while retrieving

Tags: c#, datetime, sharepoint-2013, csom

I am saving a DateTime value in one of the field in SharePoint list :

```
//request is an entity that has all he fields in the list, I am only showing DueDate in the below code
    if (txtdatepicker.Text != String.Empty)
    {
        DateTime dueDate;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(txtdatepicker.Text, out dueDate))
        {
             request.DueDate = dueDate;//Output {9/30/2017 12:00:00 AM}
        }
    }
```

The Date is correctly saved in SharePoint list as **Due Date**: `9/30/2017`.

Now the issue is when i try to retrieve this Date value :

```
if (LI[Constants.FieldName_ReqLst_DueDate] != null)
  req.DueDate = (DateTime)LI[Constants.FieldName_ReqLst_DueDate];//Output {9/29/2017 6:30:00 PM}
```

The output I get here is totally different from that of the value that is saved. How can I fetch the correct Date value from a SharPoint DateTime column?

I've tried with `DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(LI[Constants.FieldName_ReqLs‌​t_DueDate])).ToLocal‌​Time()` works fine on local machine but if deployed on the server then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the date in to local time format, as below

```
var PaymentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item["PaymentDate"].ToString()).ToLocalTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the server located?  If the server is located in a different time zone, that will affect the `ToLocalTime()` function.

A lot of site will associate a time zone with the user profile, then convert all date/time displayed to that configured value.

For the Sharepoint site you can try this:

```
if (LI[Constants.FieldName_ReqLst_DueDate] != null)
{
  // create a time zone object hard coding to local time zone
  var timeInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
  var tempDate = (DateTime)LI[Constants.FieldName_ReqLst_DueDate];
  req.DueDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(tempDate, timeInfo);
}
```

Then anyone using your site will know the time is always in the time zone you set.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check *strings* with `String.IsNullOrEmpty(myVar);`
2. I recomend to store datetime values in DB as UTC. In this case it is time-zone independent, and you will avoid winter/summer time shifts issues in future.
3. When retrieving datetime from DB, and calling `ToLocalTime()` sets time according your server time zone settings.